# Auto-generate TypeDoc command every time when gulp is run

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, typedoc

I have a problem with auto-generating command `typedoc --out path/to/documentation/ path/to/typescript/project/ --options` every time, when command gulp distribute is called.

I need to also first save code with comments in one file and then save the same code in another file but without comments and whitespaces.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you using `gulp-typedoc` ?

Comment: `I need to also first save code with comments in one file and then save the same code in another file but without comments and whitespaces.` didn't get you.

Comment: So, I have a folder with two files. First file is generated with comments (full documentation - code with comments). Name of this file is full. Second file (almost_full). This file contains only program code, without comments and whitespaces.
Whet I generated documentation first time, I used typedoc. But if it is easier with gulp-typedoc, it is no problem to use it.